# How to drag down function with recursive range changes in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have two questions for my spreadsheet data, my dataset is like following:
[dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLKFF.png)
I would like to draw a box plot using the blue-fertility as x, box plot with average and +/- standard deviation of ticks as y, like the following:
[sample box-plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SUihG.png)

My attempt was trying to get each interval of x, which is 2.1, 2.2, 2.3, ..., correspond to the ticks value inside each interval, which is 10 different values in each interval. So, I was trying to build 3 new columns: blue-fertility(x), AverageTicks(dots), StandardDeviation Ticks(bars), like the following:
[Attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9oh6f.png)

My questions:
1/ how to write the three functions in the cell and to easily drag down in each column? This dataset is pretty large, it is impossible to write function in each cells to get the results.

2/ I tried to plot the box figure using the new data I had from the attempt, but it does not look well as the sample figure I attached above. How should I draw a neat box plot using the data?

Thanks ahead!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to question 1
Formulas to calculate average values and standard deviation - see the screenshot below.
[image: Std_dev]

Comment: thanks for your help. i am not quite familiar with offset, could you help me with 10*(row()-row($B$2)), what is this meaning? I understand the 10 is at optional height of row, which should give 10 rows down, but what those row() part doing? 
Another thing, could you give me some idea about how to use these data to draw a box plot? Thanks.

Comment: `ROW()` means row number of the current cell, `ROW($B$2)` means row number of the cell, where your chart data begin (may be also $F$2 in this case). You must calculate the vertical offset of your data.  
How to draw a plot? There are many examples in youtube e.g.  
https://youtu.be/CqeEqSQRVrE

Comment: i think the third line for standard deviation has some problems here, the value is not correct. The standard deviation is working the same interval like averageif does. But when I tried the offset, it returns 160 which is the value in B2 cell, but it should return the value with all 10 times repetitions of 2.1. Then the stdev.s should work out those values standard deviation. And, hopefully it can drag down to other intervals, like averageif did. Could you help me how to fix that?

Comment: I don't see any problem here. In the 3rd row average value =58.1 and data for calculating std deviation are: 67, 63, 44, 52, 66, 44, 50, 82, 61, 52.
Std dev for these 10 numbers equals 11.9392
Have you got any different data?

Comment: hi MGonet, it works! I did not use dollar sign to fix the beginning cell. But, i still need some help, could you help me understand this OFFSET($F$8,10*(ROW()-ROW($F$8)),,10) ? This is the function i input in the cell L8 in my spreadsheet. I don't understand what is the value it returns.  Thanks.

Comment: The best way to see how it works is to use the `Evaluate Formula` tool. Here F8 is a reference cell, row offset is 0 ( ROW(L8)-ROW($F$8)=0 ), column offset is 0 (missing argument), height = 10, width = 1 (missing argument). So the formula represents the range `$F$8:$F$17`.

Comment: Hi MGonet, thanks for your clarification, could you tell me why you put 10* before (row()-row($F$8)? If row values is zero, it remains the same row, and height gives a 10 rows region. But when drag down to next cell, it should yield 10*1=10, because the beginning row is fixed, and recursively dragging down will return 20, 30,… the height gives the 10 rows height region always, but what that 10* in row argument does?

Comment: If you drag your formula 1 row down from `L8` to `L9` the row difference will be one and you need your offset to be ten, so you need to multiply row difference by 10. The reference cell is always $F$8.

Comment: Thanks MGonet, I figure it out by using the Evaluate Formula